# Google Sheet, using deleterows in script keeping formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that runs every 10 minutes and deletes 1 row on every iteration to keep always 144 rows for a 24 hours chart. It works pretty well for a sheet without formulas, but the other 3 sheets got formulas in them referring to the first one and when the script runs, they don't do what I would expect. Here's the script:

```
  var tableData = ss.getSheetByName("TableData");
  var rowsToKeep = 149;   
  var totalRows = tableData.getLastRow();
  var numToDelete = totalRows - rowsToKeep;
      if (numToDelete > 0)
       {
         tableData.deleteRows(6, numToDelete);        
}

  var chartData1 = ss.getSheetByName("ChartData1-15");
  var rowsToKeep1 = 146;   
  var totalRows1 = chartData1.getLastRow();
  var numToDelete1 = totalRows1 - rowsToKeep1;
      if (numToDelete1 > 0)
       {
         chartData1.deleteRows(3, numToDelete1);          
}


  var chartData2 = ss.getSheetByName("ChartData10-20");
  var rowsToKeep2 = 146;   
  var totalRows2 = chartData2.getLastRow();
  var numToDelete2 = totalRows2 - rowsToKeep2;
      if (numToDelete2 > 0)
       {
         chartData2.deleteRows(3, numToDelete2);          
}


  var chartData3 = ss.getSheetByName("ChartData15-64");
  var rowsToKeep3 = 146;   
  var totalRows3 = chartData3.getLastRow();
  var numToDelete3 = totalRows1 - rowsToKeep3;
      if (numToDelete3 > 0)
       {
         chartData3.deleteRows(3, numToDelete3);         
}
```

Formulas repeated in rows and columns are:

> =IF(TableData!B$3>=$A$1, TableData!B5,"")
>   =IF(TableData!B$3>=$A$1, TableData!B6,"")
>   =IF(TableData!B$3>=$A$1, TableData!B7,"")

and so on.... - for chartData1

> =IF(and(TableData!B$3>=$B$1, TableData!B$3<=$A$1), TableData!B5,"")
>   =IF(and(TableData!B$3>=$B$1, TableData!B$3<=$A$1), TableData!B6,"")
>   =IF(and(TableData!B$3>=$B$1, TableData!B$3<=$A$1), TableData!B7,"")

and so on.... - for chartData2

> =IF(TableData!B$3<=$A$1, TableData!B5,"")
>   =IF(TableData!B$3<=$A$1, TableData!B6,"")
>   =IF(TableData!B$3<=$A$1, TableData!B7,"")

and so on... - for chartData3

What happens is: in chartData1 and 3 the rows change in =IF(TableData!B$3>=$A$1, #REF!,""), like missing the reference in TableData because it gets deleted; in chartData2 the rows below are translated above carrying the down formulas with them.
Is there a way to solve my problem? Maybe a script that could recopy again the formulas from the first row (the one not deleted)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Copy the values from the cells that the formulas refer to - either up, down, or whatever appropriate.  Then overwrite them with new data.  This will keep you from having to replace formulas, which would be more tedious.

Comment: Do you mean adding something in the script that copies the values from a sheet to another? But I need the formula to display or not display a column if a number it got in the top cell is above, below, or between others numbers. I need this because I want to display in 3 different charts the top, middle and low values